# Find the index of a TabPage

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I am using a For Each loop:

```
For Each tab As TabPage in TabControl1.TabPages
```

I cannot retrieve the index of *tab*. Is there a way to do this? I am trying to see if the index is below or above the current index.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the method [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.indexof.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) of the TabPageCollection to get the Index of a Tab.

```
Dim indexOfTab As Integer = TabControl1.TabPages.IndexOf(tab)
```

Comment: Same as pluto - I wish I knew this before! :) thanks so much.

Comment: Using a For loop (not for each) seemed to solve my problem, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

There's also

```
Dim indexOfTab As Integer = TabControl1.TabPages.IndexOfKey("TabName")
```

or

```
Dim indexOfTab As Integer = TabControl1.TabPages.IndexOfKey(tab.Name)
```

This is useful if the tab page is ever removed from the collection but you want to know where it was. I know this sounds esoteric, but I've had that need quite a few times, and you can't get this information from the tab page object itself.